# Magento 2.3 - Controller plugin redirect back to form loses form values

Tags: magento2.3, plugin

I have a plugin running on the aroundExecute of the Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost controller.

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

public function __construct(
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager

)
{
    $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
}

public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
        'Error testing'
    );
    $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    return $resultRedirect->setUrl($defaultUrl);

}
```

This works fine, but all form values on the registration form are lost on redirect back.
Any idea how I can pass them back to the original form and have them repopulate the form fields?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in session as the core controller does it.
Take a look at the  `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost::execute` in the `catch` section.

```
$this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
```

But you also need to add an instance of `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` as a dependency to your class.

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

private $session;
public function __construct(
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session

)
{
    $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
    $this->resultRedirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->session = $session;
}

public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
        'Error testing'
    );
    $this->session->setCustomerFormData($subject->getRequest()->getPostValue());
    $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    return $resultRedirect->setUrl($defaultUrl);

}
```

Comment: Works like a dream :) Thank you!